# What are some alternatives to math.stackexchange where discussions are allowed?

Tags: discussion

Many question are exploratory in nature and doesn't fit in well within math.stackexchange rules. So for those questions, are there any sites similar in nature to math.stackexchange but more offer more flexibility?

Comment: It would be nice to have an alternative to recommend so that the load of moderating out discussion questions would be lightened.  Personally, I don't know of any stellar recommendations.

Comment: Better business is to not use another site. It keeps the traffic in the site. Have a label for it, have by default the label not to be included in the main pages (Home, Questions and Unanswered), and have its own page linked in the left side bar. Same would be good for homework questions.

Comment: Some related older questions: [Forum for discussion-type questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17514) and [Seeking discussion forum for mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33616). (You might check the comments posted there for some further links.)

Comment: Just in case some newcomers don't notice it among the comments: please visit an [old post on main](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95787)(non-meta) which provides a list (that is not buried under a debate on the culture).

Comment: @Boxwood That's an interesting suggestion, although the software changes required would probably prohibitive for the time being, I'd imagine. As for "keeping traffic" I do not think optimizing for traffic is currently one of our priorities. My impression is that one of our priorities is to improve site quality as a Q+A.   Discussion questions are not really Q+A, so it does not seem to serve that purpose.

Comment: If anything one of the site's growing pains is moderation keeping up with traffic.

Comment: One option none of the linked older questions seem to discuss is [the math reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/math). That looks suitable.

Comment: You could use Discord for that purpose. There's a server on discord called "Mathematics" where people can ask for help to certain questions. The server is well moderated, has various channel for various math topics like linear algebra, calculus, pre-calculus, abstract algebra, topology etc. You can use LaTeX on that server to provide your query

Comment: I see no one has mentioned [math.se chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com).  There are many chatrooms available to consult on various topics, which allow a less formal "give and take" between users.  Feel free to take a look!

Comment: @Om3ga Incidentally, there are at least three different Discord servers of significant size "called 'Mathematics' where people can ask for help to certain questions.", in addition to others not named "Mathematics" (e.g. general STEM help servers - advanced math servers - subject-area-specific servers - servers for math people at a particular university, etc.)

Comment: I would be interested in creating such a Django website with you.  Ping me in chat.

Answer (score 21):

You have more than the 20 pts. reputation needed to [talk in chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com) here, as @amWhy suggested.  At 100 pts. you would gain the privilege to create a new chatroom, but likely there are existing chatrooms suitable for exploration of math topics.

Answer (score 9):

At the risk of shameless self promotion, I used to run a Facebook group aimed at exactly this kind of thing, called [>implying we can discuss mathematics](https://www.facebook.com/groups/implyingmathematics/). I needed to step away from social media for personal reasons, and also not administrate a large group while working on my thesis, so I handed it off to some avid students who struck me as both good math students and positive members of that community. I'm still in touch with a fair few people from that experience and I would wager it's a good place for this sort of dialogue.