# Are there any alternatives to Mathematics Stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

I have been low-key using the platform for a while. I often read meta-posts and notice that there appears to be increasing discontent with the way Stack Exchange manages the sites; both with regard to moderator rights/permissions and with regard to new feature rollouts.

In light of this, I am wondering if there are any alternatives to stack exchange that allow for asking and answering questions of similar type that can be asked here but which are not under the control of the company Stack Exchange?

Comment: You can check out various similar questions from the past - but keep in mind that they are relatively old, so not all information there is necessarily reliable. On this meta: [Is there an MSE-like site that is more pleasant to work in? Or are there other solutions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16451) and [What are some alternatives to math.stackexchange where discussions are allowed?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34331) 
On MathOverflow meta: [Any other site besides mathoverflow and mathematics stackexchange?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1181)

Comment: And there is this post on the main site: [Useful mathematical fora](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95787).

Comment: 4chan has a science and mathematics subforum

Comment: The math community over at Codidact is in need of some good activity,

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think that might be a misunderstanding on your part. I think OP is commenting on widespread frustration that is aimed at the SE admins, not the MSE mods, for their efforts to undercut the hard work of mods.

Comment: When you suggest an answer here, also indicate how easy  it is to write mathematical formulas.  Let's face it, $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is easier to read than `√(b^2-4ac)`

Comment: @CameronWilliams You are probably right.

Answer (score 65):

No, not really.

Codidact is intended to replicate the experience, but activity there is low. Quora has a similar format, but the quality control is bad (for both answers and questions). Reddit has similar problems to quora. Physicsforums and AoPS are good resources, but are not really the same.

The truth is, this community is unique. It became what it is today from years of careful and deliberate cultivation. As a result, the math.se experience doesn't really exist anywhere else. I hope that the issues with the company do not cause a mass exodus, because the community would be more likely to dissipate than to relocate. That would be a great loss to the world of mathematics.

Comment: You do be spitting fax

Comment: Is there any advantage to using Physics forums/AoPS over math.se?

Comment: @TymaGaidash For olympiad/competition problems at any level, AoPS is better than MSE.

Comment: @TymaGaidash You will get a better answer asking there - asking on Math.SE will get you an incomplete answer biased towards Math.SE! (The answer here - which I fully agree with! - wonderfully demonstrates this phenomenon...)

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying math.se is better than these other sites (well, maybe quora), just that they aren't the same. I used physicsforums a lot during undergrad, and it was very helpful for physics. But the format is not the same and the way the community operates is not the same, so the experience ends up being very different. Same with AoPS. They're good resources, but would not work as math.se replacements.

Comment: Since you mention Codidact, it seems relevant to link to the math part of that site: https://math.codidact.com

Comment: it seems remiss not to mention MathOverflow. (http://mathoverflow.net/). Certainly not the same experience as Math.SE, its mission is research level mathematics, but  there is some overlap and it is at least as relevant as some of those other sites that were mentioned.

Comment: " A great loss to the world of mathematics" is probably as exaggerated as a prediction can be, as far as a "do-my-homework" site based on dopamine-triggering point earning system is concerned.

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't want to spend too much time defending the site here, so all I'll say is, it's more than that for many people.

Answer (score 14):

If you speak French then the forums on https://les-mathematiques.net/ can be pretty useful.

Clearly the experience is subpar to math.stackexchange and you have to understand French to use it, but you can still get good answers to graduate level mathematics.

Answer (score 7):

I came into online mathematics via Math Help Forum: https://mathhelpforum.com/community/

It's been around for over 15 years.

From there in 2008 I heard about ProofWiki which may be worth a glance -- it's not a help forum but a repository of mathematics in which you may find what you're seeking, but there's lots to do.